# What is the grammar of rule of this code in Objective-C or in C language?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm reading the code of [Mach Ports](http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/), I want to know what's the paradigm of a piece of code. I mean I knew the grammar of struct of objective-c, but I don't know what grammar of `message.header = (mach_msg_header_t) {......};`

The complete code is below.

```
natural_t data;

mach_port_t port;

struct {

    mach_msg_header_t header;
    mach_msg_body_t body;
    mach_msg_type_descriptor_t type;

} message;

message.header = (mach_msg_header_t) {

    .msgh_remote_port = port,
    .msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL,
    .msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND, 0),
    .msgh_size = sizeof(message)

};
```

Comment: `(mach_msg_header_t)` is a type cast.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks, but I knew it's a type cast. so I'm wondering the code of  <i>(mach_msg_header_t) {
    .msgh_remote_port = port,
  ..... };  </i> is a function? Or struct ? and " .msgh_remote_port " means what? I'm really confusing.

Comment: It seems to be struct field assignment. The `mach_msg_header_t` struct has fields named `msgh_remote_port`, `msgh_local_port` etc.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks! I understand now why the struct assignment is written like this.

Answer (score 0):

The header is assigned to the type-casted mach_msg_header_t pseudo constructor that initializes some of the fields.   A break down of the structure is available here : http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/ (partially pasted below)

```
typedef struct {
    mach_msg_bits_t msgh_bits;
    mach_msg_size_t msgh_size;
    mach_port_t msgh_remote_port;
    mach_port_t msgh_local_port;
    mach_port_seqno_t msgh_seqno;
    mach_msg_id_t msgh_id;
} mach_msg_header_t;
```

The bit you referenced, does the assignment of the low level fields in the structure and copy into the header.

```
message.header = (mach_msg_header_t) {

    .msgh_remote_port = port,
    .msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL,
    .msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND, 0),
    .msgh_size = sizeof(message)

};
```